# Game on numeric arrays

Tags: java, array

Two participants, A and B, are playing the following game:

- The initial set of games is a sequence of zeroes and ones.
- A and B
  change turns, and participant A always moves first.
- During each
  turn, a player removes one element from the sequence that satisfies
  the following: 
  It is not the first or last element. 
  It must be
  surrounded by zeroes on both sides.
- The first participant who can't take
  their turn loses the game.
- Both participants always move optimally.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer `n`, denoting the number of games. The subsequent lines describe each game in the following format:

- The first line before the sequence contains a single integer denoting the length of the sequence.
- The second line contains the sequence, i.e. a space-separated integers denoting the respective values of the initial sequence. Each element is either zero or one.

**Sample input**

```
8
61
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
28
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
28
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
15
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
5
1 0 1 0 1
6
1 0 1 0 1 1
6
0 0 0 0 0 0
7
1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

**Sample Output**

```
A
B
B
A
A
A
B
B
```

**Graphical explanation for 5th and 7th sample inputs**:

[image]

[image]

Number to be removed during each turn is marked in red.

My code:

```
 public class Solution {

 public enum Players {
              A { @Override public Players turn() {return B; }}, 
              B { @Override public Players turn() {return A; }}, 
              ;

    abstract public Players turn();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int g = in.nextInt();
    Players winner = Players.B;

    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < g; a0++){
        int n = in.nextInt();
        Integer[] sequence = new Integer[n];
        for(int sequence_i=0; sequence_i < n; sequence_i++){
            sequence[sequence_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> initial = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(sequence));
        Players current = Players.B;
        for (int i=0; i < initial.size()-1; i++) {  
            if (i > 0 && initial.get(i-1) == 0 && initial.get(i+1) == 0) {
                current = current.turn();
                winner = current;
                initial.remove(i);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    System.out.println(winner);         
    }
    in.close();
   }
}
```

Is my code logically correct? The test data is hit but I doubt anyway...

Comment: "Is my code logically correct?" On Code Review, only working code is accepted. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic]. Once you're convinced it works, we can help to make it pretty. But as long as you aren't sure, it's not fit for review.

Comment: As I said at the bottom`The test data is hit`, so on my test cases the code is working. But I may have missed some cases out of my sight...

Comment: In [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) we have point  **Correctness in unanticipated cases**, which I think fits my question.

Comment: Your example input has the first sequence on the third line instead of the second as described by 'input format'. What's going on there?

Comment: The very first line contains `n` which is number of games, and then there go line tuples: sequence length + sequence itself on every two lines. Maybe I worded it awkward, dunno how to formulate better, 'cause English is non-native for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>         for (int i=0; i < initial.size()-1; i++) {  
>             if (i > 0 && initial.get(i-1) == 0 && initial.get(i+1) == 0) {
>                 current = current.turn();
>                 winner = current;
>                 initial.remove(i);
>                 i = 0;
>             }
>         }
> ```

You don't need to do `initial.size() - 1` on each iteration.  Consider

```
        for (int i = 2; i < initial.size(); i++) {  
            if (initial.get(i) == 0 && initial.get(i - 2) == 0) {
                current = current.turn();
                initial.remove(i - 1);
                i = 1;
            }
        }
```

This starts with the *third* element.  If it's not a 0, then there is no reason to check other values.  No math needed.  If it is a 0, then it verifies that the element two places prior is a 0.  Only then does it proceed to processing.

Note that setting `i` to 1 means that it will be 2 again for the next iteration.  There were actually offsetting mistakes in the original code that made it work.  You don't need `i` to ever be 0, so setting `i` to 0 and then incrementing to 1 worked.

Comment: Thanks to this I found a mistake in my code :). I'd say it's still more logical to reason about the element you're about to remove though, despite doing `initial.size()-1` on each iteration. Otherwise i'd go with `for(int = 0; i < initial.size()-2; i++) { ... i = -1;}` And start reasoning from the first 0. Then removing i+1 if i+2 is also 0. Your post is still useful to take into consideration. It helps to look at all posibilities and then choosing the best one :)

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. By getting rid of `initial.size() - 1` on each iteration we eliminate re-calculation and this gaining performance effect?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it looks like it doesn't matter in what order the items are removed. The end result will always be the same.

If that statement is correct, your code will give the right answer for any individual game.

There is however 1 edge case for which you will give the wrong result. It's for a game that has no possible moves from the start. (For example: 0 1 1). This can be easily fixed by not setting the winner during the loop, but just after the loop. All we need to do is "swap" players 1 more time after a game to see who won.

Since we don't actually need to keep track of the winner anymore (you print the winner right after a game and don't use the variable after that) we might as well just get rid of the variable altoghether.

---

As for the code review. Let me start by giving my resulting code after all improvements to what you currently have and then point out some things I did.

```
public class Solution {
    public enum Player {
        A {@Override public Player turn() {return B;}},
        B {@Override public Player turn() {return A;}},;

        public abstract Player turn();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int nbOfGames = in.nextInt();
            Player currentPlayer = Player.A;
            for (int i = 0; i < nbOfGames; i++) {
                currentPlayer = playGame(readSequence(in), currentPlayer);
                System.out.println(currentPlayer);
                currentPlayer = Player.A; //In a new game always player A's turn first.
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> readSequence(Scanner in) {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sequence.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        return sequence;
    }

    /**
     * returns the winner.
     */
    public static Player playGame(List<Integer> sequence, Player startingPlayer) {
        Player currentPlayer = startingPlayer;
        for (int i = 1; i < sequence.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (sequence.get(i - 1) == 0 && (sequence.get(i + 1) == 0)) {
                currentPlayer = currentPlayer.turn();
                sequence.remove(i);
                i = 0; // set to 0 so it turns to 1 again after this iteration ends.
            }
        }
        return currentPlayer.turn();
    }
}
```

Renamed Players -> Player. An instance of this "class" is a single player.

Split up reading input sequence to its own method.

Split up playing a single game to its own method.

When reading the input, directly put it into a `List<Integer>` instead of converting it afterwards.

Removed `Players winner` since it's obsolete.

Renamed `sequence_i` to `i` in for loop for reading input sequence.

Renamed `g` to `nbOfGames` to clarify its meaning.

Renamed `a0` to `i` when looping over `nbOfGames` (No clash with other index names since they are in their own methods).

Used Try-with-resource feature so I don't have to care about closing the scanner.

Made the choice explicit of which player has to start for each sequence.
Indirectly fixed the ambiguity of who wins when a game has no valid turns to start with.

Stored the sequence as a `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`. It's always better to code against an interface instead of a specific implementation. In this case we only care that it's a `List` not what kind of list.

Perhaps some more things that I did unconciously.

A fun side effect of splitting off the `playGame` method like this is that it's also easier to test it without user input. You can just create a list with your wanted test sequence and see if the method returns the correct player.

Comment: However, the following condition is wrong: `the winner of last game has to play first in the next`. In the OP there were explicitly said: **participant A always moves first**

Comment: How to adapt the code in this way? 'cause now either with commented or uncommented line it gives the wrong results.

Comment: Ah whoops. I missed that part in the original post. Just change the commented line to: `currentPlayer = Player.A;`

Comment: Thx @mdfst13 I editted my answer to use the correct index. And changed the commented part to set it to Player.A after each game.